# MySQL table not updating when flag set run in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, smarty

So... Star Wars code again...

I have some code that I want to change a boolean value in a MySQL database from true to false, based on a button push.  The specific code included relates to people who have stated that their chosen character uses a lightsaber.  I want to apply a flag to a view called "gameview" whose rows will be counted until there is one character left.  If there's a false value in the flag column, then it is not counted.

I have created a number of classes, methods and controllers as well as a view.  The pages all display as they should.  However, when the relevant button is pressed, the code is not changing the flags as expected.  I am fairly sure that the MySQL code is good, so it is something to do with the PHP code.
The method is in a class called gameview.class.php

Class Codes:

```
Public function iterateGameView($id)
    {   $changeFlag = "UPDATE gameview SET flag :flag WHERE id = :id";
        $stmt = $this->Conn->prepare($changeFlag);
        $stmt->execute(array([':flag' => false, ':id' => [$id]]));
    }
```

Lightsaber Class Code

```
public function noLightsaberUsed()
    {
        $query = "select * from person, weapon, person_weapon 
WHERE flag = 0 AND person.id = person_weapon.person_id AND person_weapon.weapon_id = weapon.id and weapon.name != 'Lightsaber'
AND person.name NOT IN (select person.name from person, weapon, person_weapon WHERE person.id = person_weapon.person_id
AND person_weapon.weapon_id = weapon.id and weapon.name = 'Lightsaber')";
        $stmt = $this->Conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute(array());
        return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    }
```

Lightsaber controller

```
<?php
$lightsaber = new lightsaber($Conn);
$gameView = new gameView($Conn);

if ($_POST) {
    if ($_POST['lightsaber'] = 1) {
        $lightsabers = $lightsaber->noLightsaberUsed();
        $smarty->assign('lightsabers_used', $lightsabers);
        $lightsabersFlag = array($lightsabers, 'id', 'flag');
        for ($i = 0; $i <= count($lightsabersFlag); $i++) {
            $gameView->iterateGameView($lightsabersFlag[$i]);

        }

    } elseif ($_POST['lightsaber'] = 2) {
        $lightsabers = $lightsaber->lightsaberUsed();
        $smarty->assign('lightsabers_used', $lightsabers);
        $lightsabersFlag = array($lightsabers, 'id', 'flag');
        for ($i = 0; $i <= count($lightsabersFlag); $i++) {
            $gameView->iterateGameView($lightsabersFlag[$i]);
        }
    }

    $count = $gameView->countGameView();
    if ($count > 1) {
        header("Location: index.php?p=rebel");
    } elseif ($count < 1) {
        header("Location: index.php?p=fail");
    } else {
        header("Location: index.php?p=gameview");
    }

}
?>
```

The bit that I believe that I am stuck on is the iterateGameView method.  I'm a relative novice with PHP and MySQL and this is the first time I've attempted a prepared statement.

Comment: `$_POST['lightsaber'] = 1` - You're assigning 1 instead of comparing

Comment: Apologies....  this refers to code in a template where a button is assigned a value of "1".

Comment: Also, you're adding an extra array element that is probably throwing off your query. `[':flag' => false, ':id' => [$id]]`

Comment: The confusion that I have is that I have an array variable called $lightsabersFlag, and I want to use that array to set the flags in my main view.  I cannot for the life of me seem to be able to create the code that will do that.  I know what I want it to do:  UPDATE gameview SET flag = false where id (is in $lightsaberFlag) but no amount of of research for this novice is helping.

Comment: _“this refers to code in a template where a button is assigned a value of "1"”_ - if it was a mere assignment, then why is it wrapped in an `if`?

Comment: Hi Misorude:  Because I haven't posted the entire code.  There are 2 buttons on the page, one is assigned 1 and the other 2.  if button Yes is clicked, the first code runs, if No is clicked, different code is run.  Simples!

Comment: At the moment, the "no" option will never run because you're assigning 1 to `$_POST['lightsaber']` instead of comparing it. The other issue is the update query I mentioned in my second comment. Remove the brackets from `[$id]`

Comment: I will update the code, as it's wrapped in another if statement.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure `$lightsabersFlag` is doing what you want it to do. `$lightsabers` is at least 1 row, so that's an array. This means that `$lightsabersFlag` contains an array inside of an array. Your `for` is iterating through `$lightsabersFlag`, so the first loop would be `$lightsabers` (a multidimensional array), the second would be `id`, and the third would be `flag`

Comment: The best way to troubleshoot is taking advantage of logging or `var_dump`. Find out what variables are being passed along the way so you can make sure it matches what you think it should be.

Comment: OK, that kind of makes sense.  So as my $lightsabers is already an array, the $lightsaberFlag is superfluous to needs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207844/discussion-between-stevie-and-aynber).